# Delete user in transaction

Tags: users, database

I'm having trouble figuring out why the following code isn't working in Drupal 7. `_queue_processor` is a cron queue processor function:

```php
function _queue_processor($uid) {

    $transaction = db_transaction();

    watchdog('debug', 'transaction created'); // This will not be called.

    try {
      user_delete($uid);
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
      // A problem occurred. Rollback transaction.
      $transaction->rollback();
      throw $e;
    }
    // Rollback intentionally.
    if (variable_get('some_var', FALSE)) {
      $transaction->rollback();
    }
}
```

The code never makes it past the `$transaction = db_transaction();` line. However, if I remove the transaction and try/catch, `user_delete()` is called just fine, and the transaction that `user_delete_multiple()` creates within itself works as well.

Is there something wrong with putting `user_delete()` within a transaction? I know it already uses one, but I need to be able to run the deletion and then conditionally rollback afterwards, and I'd rather not do this by throwing an exception in an implementation of hook_user_delete() to force rollback.

I am using MariaDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, this can only be done using exceptions. Here is a minimal example. Note that the module in the code example is called `module`.

```php
function module_queue_processor($uid) {
  try {
    // Delete user.
    user_delete($uid);
  }
  catch (DebugException $e) {
    // Catch custom exception. The inner transaction has been rolled back.
    // @todo The exception is still logged to watchdog in user_delete().
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_module_implements_alter().
 */
function module_module_implements_alter(&$implementations, $hook) {
  if ($hook == 'user_delete') {
    // Remove node_user_delete() to ensure nodes are not deleted.
    unset($implementations['node']);

    // Move module_user_delete() to the beginning of the list.
    // This ensures that custom processing is done first.
    // This may not be necessary, but it's a good idea.
    $group = $implementations['module'];
    $implementations = ['module' => $group] + $implementations;
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_user_delete().
 *
 * This hook is called before all others.
 */
function module_user_delete($account) {
  $uid = $account->uid;
  $name = $account->name;
  
  // Prevent deletion of anonymous and root users.
  if ($uid == 0 || $uid == 1) {
    watchdog('module', 'Cannot delete user with UID @uid.', array('@uid' => $uid), WATCHDOG_ERROR);
    return;
  }

  // It is not necessary to pass the transaction object to functions. The
  // transaction will automatically be committed when all open transaction
  // objects go out of scope.
  // For more information: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/285032
  $transaction = db_transaction();

  try {
    // Temporarily use strict error handler to throw exceptions for warnings and
    // notices. Without this, warnings might cause content to be not deleted
    // without a rollback of user deletion.
    set_error_handler('module_custom_error_handler');

    ...
  }
  catch (Exception $e) {
    // Rollback the transaction.
    $transaction->rollback();

    // Log the exception.
    $message = '%type while deleting user %name with UID %uid. Transaction not committed. !message in %function (line %line of %file).';
    $variables = array(
      '%name' => $name,
      '%uid' => $uid,
    );

    watchdog_exception('module', $e, $message, $variables);

    // Throw the exception again to halt user deletion.
    throw $e;
  }
  finally {
    // Restore the pre-existing error handler.
    restore_error_handler();
  }

  // Rollback intentionally.
  if (variable_get('module_dry_run', FALSE)) {
    $transaction->rollback();

    // Trigger transaction rollback inside user_delete_multiple().
    throw new DebugException($message);
  }
}

/**
 * Custom error handler used to make non-errors into exceptions.
 *
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241728/can-i-try-catch-a-warning
 */
function module_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
  // Error was suppressed with the @-operator.
  if (error_reporting() === 0) {
    return FALSE;
  }

  throw new ErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline);
}

/**
 * Custom exception used to trigger transaction rollback for dry run.
 */
class DebugException extends Exception {}
```